# How do I change the msg.value for my smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I am trying to make a simple contract that can display your wallet balance and send ether to another wallet in Remix IDE. I want a user to be able to change the msg.value, how do I do that in Remix besides the Value in "deploy & run transactions" menu? Thanks

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Ethereum {
  address private owner = msg.sender;
  
  constructor() {
  }

  function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        
        return owner.balance;
    }

  function sendViaCall(address payable _to) public payable {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using the Remix VM emulator, and not a connected provider: No other way besides the "Value" input in the "Deploy & run transactions" tab... What's your goal? What's the reason behind looking for another way? Maybe there's another solution to your issue.

Comment: It is a school project and I am building a crypto currency wallet with Flutter. What would be the other way of doing it?

Comment: Regarding Remix VM, I am using Injected Web3 on Rinkeby testnet.

Comment: Great. Then you're able to interact with the contract on its Rinkeby address from the Flutter app - you don't need remix for that... Unfortunately mobile development and interacting with contracts from mobile is not my expertise, but it seems that there is a [port](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3_provider) of the well-known [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/) library for Flutter, that might allow you to connect to a Rinkeby node provider, perform read-only calls to the contract, and send requests to the user's mobile wallet (such as MetaMask) to sign transactions as well.

Comment: Will look into it. Thank you a lot for your input